# Can named elites in daily missions be farmed for Phoenix creds?

Tags: the-division

Killing named elites, whether on mission or not, gives some small amount of Phoenix creds (1-3 AFAIK).

But if I'd kill a named elite on daily mission, then die, respawn from checkpoint, will the subsequent kills to the same elite generate more Phoenix drops?

Comment: If you're doing missions on Hard or Challenging you'll get credits as a mission completion reward.

Comment: @DavidYell you do, but _only once_ per mission, so they cannot be farmed.

Comment: You can only earn the *daily* rewards once per day, but unless I'm mistaken you can repeat the Challenge mode as many times as you want for 30 credits + a high end drop.

Comment: @twobugs: good to know, I didn't realize that. In game wording suggested it's just more difficult daily mission.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those Bosses on missions will not respawn if you are killing them and then die. "Tested" this yesterday with Larae Barrett.

If you are talking about Bullet King: This issue will get patched today. The [patch notes](http://tomclancy-thedivision.ubi.com/game/en-gb/news/detail.aspx?c=tcm:154-242994-16&ct=tcm:148-76770-32) are stating, you will now get phoenix credits in the darkzone per 30(+) mob, so this may become an alternative.

Edit: The following part will be patched "later" :
Phoenix Credits drop have been increased on lvl 31 and 32 enemies in the Dark Zone.

Comment: The phoenix credit drop in the DZ has been moved back to a later patch now.

Comment: Yeah... too bad. Wrote that answer before the downtime and all the mess.

Comment: I accidentally killed Bullet King's crew before anyways...